# How to force policy-kit agent to show full information about command line arguments

Tags: policykit, pkexec

I am using Ubuntu Mate 20.04 and `pkexec` to launch apps with admin privileges if needed.

However, when policy agent kit asking to authorize request, there is no enough information to make a decision. For example, if I run

```
pkexec sh -c 'echo hello'
```

I'll see this promt:

[image: policy-kit-agent]

Note that there is no information about the command I'm trying to execute. So, it would look like the same for dangerous

```
pkexec sh -c 'rm -rf /'
```

How can I tweak my setup by configuring or changing agent so I can see more information (e.g. full command line) about action I'm asked to authorize?

Answer (score 1):

The variable responsible for full command line with arguments is `command_line`. To change it, one can create a custom policy as `man pkexec` page suggests.

However, I've ended up editing LC_MESSAGES. My locale is en_US, so I've done these steps:

1. copied `/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/polkit-1.mo`
2. unpacked it with `msgunfmt polkit-1.mo -o polkit-1.po`
3. edited `polkit-1.po`

```
msgid "Authentication is needed to run `$(program)' as the super user"
msgstr "Authentication is needed to run '$(program)' as the super user"
```

to

```
msgid "Authentication is needed to run `$(program)' as the super user"
msgstr "Authentication is needed to run '$(program)' ('$(command_line)') as the super user"
```

and several similar lines too.

4. packed it back with `msgfmt polkit-1.po -o polkit-1.mo`
5. put it into `/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/polkit-1.mo`
6. restarted polkit daemon `systemctl restart polkit`

And now I can get the full command
[image]

Comment: One minor issue is quotes, but I think it's ok

Comment: You have to report your idea upstream as bug-report or pull-request. Otherwise it will be implemented only on your machine and rest of the world can't use it.

Comment: @N0rbert, that's a nice idea, thanks. However, my solution is just a quick hack, not a proper solution. Changing the original message could break language packs (because msgid contains template itself). I think a better place for full command line would be `Details` block.

Comment: As for the creating an issue, I've tried to register to freedesktop gitlab with 3 different types of login, and got 500 from each of them. Guess I'll try again later :(

Comment: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/polkit/polkit/-/issues/147